# OpenJPA reports no current Transaction inside method annotated @Transactional

Tags: jpa, openjpa, apache-tomee

I have a very strange problem which I have never encountered before.  I have some methods in JSF which are marked `@Transactional`.  But when I call the fileDb.flush() function in the example below

```
@Transactional
public String toggleHide() {
    fileBean.setFile(fileDb.updateFile(fileBean.getFile()));
    if (getEvent().getSubType().equals("note")) {
        // note
        for (Note note : fileBean.getFile().getNotes()) {
            if (note.getId() == getEvent().getEventId()) {
                note.setHide(opposite(getEvent().isHidden()));
                fileDb.flush();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error

```
<openjpa-2.4.3-r422266:1833086 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Can only perform operation while a transaction is active.
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.assertActiveTransaction(BrokerImpl.java:4729)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.assertActiveTransaction(DelegatingBroker.java:1385)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:663)
at org.apache.webbeans.custom.persistence.EntityManager$$OwbNormalScopeProxy0.flush(javax/persistence/EntityManager.java)
at uk.me.kissy.database.db.file.FileDb.flush(FileDb.java:379)
at uk.me.kissy.database.db.file.FileDb$$OwbNormalScopeProxy0.flush(uk/me/kissy/database/db/file/FileDb.java)
at uk.me.kissy.file.beans.EventsBean.toggleHide(EventsBean.java:117)
```

is there any way to check the status of the current transaction?

Comment: Is the class that contains toggleHide a CDI bean?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes it is

Comment: @BalusC i am calling the function from JSF

Comment: and where does the EntityManger comes from?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli the EntityManager is injected from TomEE inside the FileDb which is an ApplicationScoped e.g. public File updateFile(File file) {
  if (!em.contains(file)) {
   file = em.merge(file);
  }
  return file;
 }

Comment: how does your persistence.xml look like?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli it's pretty big but nothing unusual. Thanks anyway. Just wanted to know if there is done way to debug when a session is not getting initialised

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195206/discussion-between-mitchbroadhead-and-simon-martinelli).

Comment: Post your entire class